# Fedora21: Only three movie options (AVI JPEG, AVI Raw, Frameserver)? No XVid! Why?

Tags: edit-mode, video

For video editing I'm learning blender from a youtube tutorial, but I get quickly stuck when I am supposed to choose the preferred output movie format. The favorite XVid is not there. I have tried to install everything related to XVid, but still to no avail. What am I missing  here?

Thank you!

Rob.

Comment: Are you getting Blender from the fedora repo's? Their builds aren't necessarily going to work properly (they aren't built by the Blender foundation). Try getting it from Blender.org and see if that works.

Comment: Sounds like it was built without ffmpeg support.

Answer (score 1):

If you get the latest download from blender.org you'll have
all kinds of format choices including XVid[image]

Answer (score 1):

Xvid Codec is not typically being shipped with the operating system, so you have to install it manually.

Xvid Codec Download page: https://www.xvid.com/download/